# how to pass extra tags in success message mixin

Tags: django

I tried this in the views.py by passing the extra_tags but it did not work for me .please suggest suggest another approach for this

views.py

```
class CustomPasswordResetConfirmView(SuccessMessageMixin, PasswordResetConfirmView):
success_message = "Your password has been set. You may go ahead and log in now. "
extra_tags = 'alert-success'

def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
    return (self.success_message, self.extra_tags)
```

login.html

```
{% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}

        {% if message.extra_tags == 'alert-success' %}
        <!-- alert-warning-green -->
        <div class="alert-bx alert-warning-green mt-3">
           <i class="icon-checked b-6 alert-icon mr-2"></i> {{message}}
        </div>
        <!-- alert-warning-green END -->
        {% endif %}

        {% if message.extra_tags == 'alert-danger' %}
        <!-- error-alert -->
        <div class="alert-bx error-alert mt-3">
           <i class="icon-warning-triangle alert-icon mr-2"></i> {{message}}
        </div>
        <!-- error-alert END -->
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_success_message` returns a string message and does not support `extra_tags`.

In order to support it, you have to modify `form_valid` function in `SuccessMessageMixin`.

The default function is defined:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        success_message = self.get_success_message(form.cleaned_data)
        if success_message:
            messages.success(self.request, success_message)
        return response
```

To support your `extra_tags` you have to change to this:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        success_message = self.get_success_message(form.cleaned_data)
        if success_message:
            messages.success(self.request, success_message, extra_tags=self.extra_tags)
        return response
```

and remove your modified `get_success_message`

Answer (score 1):

```
class CustomPasswordResetConfirmView(SuccessMessageMixin, PasswordResetConfirmView):
success_message = "Your password has been set. You may go ahead and log in now. "

def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
      return messages.success(request,self.success_message, extra_tags = 'alert-success')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without class based view I coded like this to use both extra_tags & level_tag to find which function is sending message:

in view.py side

```
messages.success(request, "username", extra_tags = 'log')
```

in html side

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for msg in messages %}
        {% if 'log' in msg.extra_tags %}
            <p class="alert alert-{{msg.level_tag}}"> user {msg}} Loged in Successfuly...! </p>
```